# Facebook PHP SDK - how to get posts by hashtag

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to get all posts with a certain hashtag via Facebook PHP SDK and all I find are deprecated or incomplete solutions.

What I found was /search?q=HASHTAG but my problem there is that I don't even know how to get the access token with the new SDK. Can anyone provide a COMPLETE working example of how to get an access token for this kind of request?

Thanks in advance, this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no search type for hashtags in the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

...and Public Post search is no longer available according to the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).

There is the Public Feed API, but you cannot apply at this time: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

**Meaning, it´s not possible.**